# How to test imports/exports with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, jestjs

This is the structure I have:

[image]

As you see I have 100% test coverage on the file `shipments.js` which are the tests below:

```
import shipmentsPagination, {
  setFilters,
  removeFilter,
  toggleFiltersModal,
  setCSVDataAction,
} from '../../actions/shipments';

describe('shipments redux actions', () => {
  it('should test setCSVDataAction', () => {
    const result = setCSVDataAction({
      itemsCount: 0,
      shipments: [],
    });

    expect(result.type).toEqual('SET_CSV_DATA');
    expect(result.payload).toEqual({
      shipmentsCSV: {
        itemsCount: 0,
        shipments: [],
      },
    });
  });

  it('should test toggleFiltersModal', () => {
    const result = toggleFiltersModal(true);

    expect(result.type).toEqual('TOGGLE_SHIPMENTS_FILTERS_MODAL');
  });

  it('should test removeFilter', () => {
    const filters = {
      shipmentId: '123',
      status: 'received',
      carrier: 'FedEx',
      shippedFrom: 'Dallas',
      shippedTo: 'NY',
      shippedDate: '10/13/2018',
      shipmentType: 'Colocation Hardware',
    };

    const result = removeFilter(filters);

    expect(result.type).toEqual('REMOVE_SHIPMENTS_FILTER');
    expect(result.payload).toEqual({ [filters]: '' });
  });

  it('should test shipmentsPagination', () => {
    const result = shipmentsPagination({
      page: 2,
      pageSize: 25,
    });

    expect(result.type).toEqual('UPDATE_SHIPMENTS_PAGINATION');
    expect(result.payload).toEqual({ page: 2, pageSize: 25 });
  });

  it('should test setFilters', () => {
    const result = setFilters({
      shipmentId: '123',
      status: 'Received',
      carrier: 'FedEx',
      shippedFrom: 'Houston - HOU02',
      shippedTo: 'Herp',
      shippedDate: '1/24/2019',
      shipmentType: 'Colocation Hardware',
    });

    expect(result.type).toEqual('SET_SHIPMENTS_FILTERS');
    expect(result.payload).toEqual({
      shipmentId: '123',
      status: 'Received',
      carrier: 'FedEx',
      shippedFrom: 'Houston - HOU02',
      shippedTo: 'Herp',
      shippedDate: '1/24/2019',
      shipmentType: 'Colocation Hardware',
    });
  });
});
```

And as you may see, it says `index.js` has no coverage on line #1.

`index.js` is this:

```
import shipments from './shipments';

export default {
  shipments,
};
```

So how I can test that import/export in order to get 100% test coverage?

Comment: Obligatory "100% coverage is not a goal unto itself, you **could** just leave it alone" comment :)

Comment: not a answer but : you could simply ignore the index.js in the coverage calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see of your code just import `shipmentsPagination` from `index.js` in the test:

```
import defaultExport from '../../actions/';  // import the default export from index.js
const { shipments: shipmentsPagination } = defaultExport; // and use it to get shipmentsPagination
import {
  setFilters,
  removeFilter,
  toggleFiltersModal,
  setCSVDataAction,
} from '../../actions/shipments'; // everything else can come from shipments.js
```

Importing `shipmentsPagination` from `index.js` will make sure the `export` line in `index.js` gets tested.

Answer (score 0):

@mystackrunnethover is kind of right, it's not exactly necessary to get coverage of that line, but, just in case:

I use these tests as "sanity tests" to also ensure Jest is even running.

A common pitfall is to assume that `imported_thing.toBeTruth()` will fail if the import didn't work. It won't - `imported_thing` will be an empty object, which is truthy.

Here's what we use:

```
import Account from '/account';

//describe block

expect(Account).toBeTruthy();

expect(Object.keys(Account).length > 0).toBe(true);
```

This, of course, only works if whatever `Account` is actually has properties (and is supposed to). Another method is to specifically check for properties you are expecting.

Comment: I did what you said and now I am getting this: https://monosnap.com/file/oKNvsgI9SdIdaKyBUrXBz65L6Z7jTV which is so confusing.

Comment: I don't know what that is, sorry.